# Getting the newest revision from a table via SQL

Tags: sql

I have a database that looks like this:

```
ID   parent   name              description           _record_status   _log_user   _log_timestamp         _log_type 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    1        This is a rwo!    Test content          active           1           2012-01-29 15:49:21    create
2    1        This is a row!    Test Content          active           1           2012-01-29 15:52:14    revision
3    3        Another record!   More content          active           1           2012-01-29 15:58:43    create    
4    4        Deleted Record    More content          active           1           2012-01-29 15:58:43    create    
5    4        Deleted Record    More content          deleted          1           2012-01-29 15:58:43    destroy
```

I want to be able to select the newest row for each record, where the record isn't deleted. So for example, the output I'd expect is:

```
ID   name
------------------
2    This is a row!
3    Another Record!
```

Is there a way to do this via SQL that is efficient, and if not, what might I want to do in PHP to accomplish this?

**Would having a separate version of each table for revisions be the way to go here?**

Comment: You want the newest parent based on highest ID, but if the highest ID is deleted, you don't want that parent at all?

Comment: @ypercube PHP is mentioned and the OP's other questions are all MySQL. I'd say it's almost certainly that.

Comment: @Yuck: Yeah, PHP has high correlation with MySQL but stil not 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd get the highest record per `parent` first, then excluded anything that has been `deleted`:

```
SELECT YourTable.ID, YourTable.name
FROM YourTable INNER JOIN (
  SELECT parent, MAX(_log_timestamp) MaxLogTS
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY parent) T ON YourTable.parent = T.parent
                    AND YourTable._log_timestamp = T.MaxLogTS
WHERE YourTable._record_status != 'deleted'
```

This can be slightly optimized if you know that `ID` values are always in ascending time order. Then you could base the `MAX` record comparison on `ID` rather than a date and time value.

Comment: An index on `(parent, _log_timestamp)` would help efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL, try this:

```
select * from
(select id, name, _record_status from
 (select parent, id, name, _record_status
  from your_table
  order by parent, _log_timestamp desc) v
 group by parent) q
where _record_status <> 'deleted'
```